# Gather image file paths Recursively in PHP

Tags: php, iteration

I am working on a pretty large PHP class that does a lot of stuff with Image Optimization from the Command line, you basically pass the program an `Image path` or a `Folder path` that has multiple images inside of it.  It then runs the files through up to 5 other command line programs that optimize images.

Below is part of a loop that gathers the images paths, if the path is a Folder instead of an image path, it will iterate over all the images in the folder and add them to the image array.

So far I have everything working for single images and images in 1 folder.  I would like to modify this section below so it could recursively go deeper then 1 folder to get the image paths.

Could someone possibly show me how I could modify this below to accomplish this?

```
// Get files 
if (is_dir($path))
{
    echo 'the path is a directory, grab images in this directory';
    $handle = opendir($path);
    // FIXME : need to run recursively
    while(FALSE !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        if(is_dir($path.self::DS.$file))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if( ! self::is_image($path.self::DS.$file))
        {
            continue;
        }
        $files[] = $path.self::DS.$file;
    }
    closedir($handle);



}else{
    echo 'the path is an Image and NOT a directory';
    if(self::is_image($path))
    {   
        echo 'assign image Paths to our image array to process = '. $path. '<br><br>';
        $files[] = $path;
    }
}

if (!count($files))
{
    throw new NoImageFoundException("Image not found : $path");
}
```

---

### UPDATE

@Chris's answer got me looking at the Docs and I found an example that I modified to this that seems to work

```
public static function find_recursive_images($path) {
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
                                              RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
    foreach ($iterator as $path) {
      if ($path->isDir()) {
         //skip directories
         continue;
      } else {
         $files[] = $path->__toString();
      }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

...

```
$files = self::find_recursive_images($path);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($files);
echo '</pre>';
exit();
```

The output is JUST the filenames and there path like this which is my ultimate goal, so far this works perfect but as always if there is a better way I am all for improving

```
(
    [0] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\css3-generator.png
    [1] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\css3-please.png
    [2] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\css3-tools-10.png
    [3] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\fb.jpg
    [4] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\mysql.gif
    [5] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\OriginalImages\css3-generator.png
    [6] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\OriginalImages\css3-please.png
    [7] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\OriginalImages\css3-tools-10.png
    [8] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\OriginalImages\fb.jpg
    [9] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\OriginalImages\mysql.gif
    [10] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\OriginalImages\support-browsers.png
    [11] => E:\Server\_ImageOptimize\img\testfiles\support-browsers.png
)
```

Comment: You can use the (default) `LEAVES_ONLY` mode of `RecursiveIteratorIterator` in conjunction with the `SKIP_DOTS` option of the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`. This would allow you to skip the `isDir()` check inside the loop. I'd also recommend `getPathname()` in place of `__toString()` (it's just more descriptive).

Comment: Great on the `getPathname()` I was looking for a better one but the others I tried only shows the filename so this is good.  Ill have to look at the other stuff you mentioned, thanks

Comment: @salethe I am unable to find much information on `LEAVES_ONLY mode of RecursiveIteratorIterator in conjunction with the SKIP_DOTS` could you possibly show me how to implement it?

Comment: You place those class constants in the constructor for RecursiveIteratorIterator (`$mode`) and RecursiveDirectoryIterator (`$flags`) respectively.

Comment: @salethe thank you!  I have been playing around testing for the past hour, from what I can tell so far...Changing `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST` to `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY`  
Stops any Directories from showing up even without using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` I am still testing do know anything about this?  I am not sure what `LEAVES_ONLY` and `CHILD_FIRST` are actually doing

Comment: for those RecursiveIteratorIterator modes are, see a quick example at http://codepad.viper-7.com/bjIEjM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While andreas' answer probably works, you can also let PHP 5's [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursivedirectoryiterator.construct.php) do that work for you and use a more OOP approach.

Here's a simple example:

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));

while ($it->valid())
{
  if ($it->isDot())
    continue;

  $file = $it->current();
  if (self::is_image($file->pathName))
  {
    $files[] = $file->pathName;
  }

  $it->next();
}
```

Edit:

Alternatively, you could try this (copied from Zend_Translate_Adapter):

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveRegexIterator(
                    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME),
                    '/^(?!.*(\.svn|\.cvs)).*$/', RecursiveRegexIterator::MATCH
                ),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
            );

foreach ($it as $dir => $info)
{
  var_dump($dir); 
}
```

Cheers

Chris

Comment: Thanks for example, actually I had to add back in a lot of stuff on andreas code that he left out, like paths were not getting assigned to array or anything and it did not iterate correctly.  I know he had the right idea though. You route is the way I would like to go but I am having some trouble with it still,  Right below `if ($it->isDot()){` I added an echo message to see what is happening and one  below where it checks the image, I then run the script but it gets into an infinite loop of showing my message I set for `if ($it->isDot()){` ...continue to next message

Comment: ... The structure I am testing on is a folder with 4 images and 1 folder with another 4 images.  So the folder I run it on has 4 images and 1 sub-folder, that sub-folder has 4 images as well.  Any more tips, appreciate the help

Comment: That's weird, do you have a symlink in there somehwere or something? Is this a svn or git project? What happens when you dump `$it->current()` instead? Do you see whats happening then? I added an alternative way (the way Zend does it) that applies a RegexIterator to exclude certain directories, you might want to try that.

Comment: while you posted this I was working on something I found in the docs, it seems to work perfect, Ill add it to the bottom of my question above if you want to see it..

Comment: Okay, glad it's working for you. Maybe it's a windows thing, I tested my code and it worked for me. Cheers

Comment: Possibly, I will accept our answer as it is what got me looking in the right direction.  If you have the time could you possibly check my function above on your OS?

Comment: Thanks. Sure, what should I check? I tried it and it works on my OS (Fedora Linux) if that's what you meant?

Comment: Yes thats great, The code I have been working on was wrote with Linux in mind and it's been a challenge trying to make it work on Windows and Linux so thats all I was wanting to know if it worked on Linux since its working on windows now, thanks for the help

Comment: if ($it->isDot())
    continue;
will result in an infinite loop since $it->next() is not executed

Answer (score 1):

Create a recursive function to read a directory, then read further if a directory is found during the loop.

Something along the line of:

```
function r_readdir($path) {
   static $files = array();
   if(!is_dir($path)) {
      echo 'the path is an Image and NOT a directory';
      if(self::is_image($path))
      {   
         echo 'assign image Paths to our image array to process = '. $path. '<br><br>';
         $files[] = $path;
      }
   } else {
      while(FALSE !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
      {
         if(is_dir($path.self::DS.$file))
         {
            r_readdir($path.self::DS.$file);
         }
         if( ! self::is_image($path.self::DS.$file))
         {
            continue;
         }
      }
      closedir($handle);
   }
   return $files;
}
```